# Is there a slot type for Amazon Lex that accepts dots?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to create a slot type for users to enter input similiar to a URL, with multiple dots (in my case, more than a URL). Is this possible? At the moment I'm using alphanumeric but it seems to be bugging out as it doesn't accept "."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon Lex provides the ability to use custom Lambda functions to extend the range of capabilities that you can add to a Lex bot. You can create a custom Lambda function to validate the input data according to your needs.

Take a look at the Lex programming model [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/programming-model.html)

[This video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0j9iRUQJDBU&ab_channel=FooBarServerless) will help as well.